# Creating XML file using XML Document Class/ XMLTextWriter Class

Tags: xml

Whenever I create or read a XML document using XML Document Class or XMLTextWriter/reader Class an exe(WebDev.WebServer40.EXE) comes up in task Manager. And I am not able to Delete created XML file without ending this process. I was trying to write a program which will create a XML, read it and then will delte it. But due to this process, I am not able to delete created XML file programatically.

Comment: FYI, you should not use `XmlTextWriter` directly. Use `XmlWriter.Create` as shown in Darin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you are not properly disposing the underlying stream. Here's an example of how to do this properly:

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("foo.xml"))
{
    // TODO: use the writer here to write to the XML file
}
```

Same thing with the reader:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("foo.xml"))
{
    // TODO: use the reader here to read the XML file
}
```

Now because the reader is properly disposed the file will not be *locked* and you will be able to modify/delete it from other processes as well. Also don't forget that writing to a file from concurrent threads could problematic so you must ensure to properly synchronize the access to this shared resource using proper synchronizing mechanisms such as the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) or a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Comment: I am using XMLDocument class to creat document. Not able to past whole code so just pasting prime lines. XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); rootElement = doc.CreateElement("SuperProProductList"); doc.InsertAfter(rootElement, comment); productElement = doc.CreateElement("Product"); /* Code for adding various attributes of Product. Finally file path is given and doc is created. */ string file = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, @"App_Data\SuperProductListUsingXMLDocumentClass.xml"); doc.Save(file); In this code where should I use solution given by you?

Comment: @Chat if you are using this code you should be OK, the file is not being locked here. Maybe some other part of your code opens the file without releasing it.

Comment: Anyway, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Will recheck my code again.